# ACI openldap and phpldapadmin

Tags: openldap

I have an openldap-2.4.23 working in a debian system. I use phpldapadmin to access the schema and manage it.

I have this schema:

o=us

-cn=admin,o=us

-dc=com,o=us

--dc=example,dc=com,o=us

---cn=admin-2,dc=example,dc=com,o=us

---ou=people,dc=example,dc=com,o=us

----uid=user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com,o=us

----uid=user2,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com,o=us

----uid=user3,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com,o=us

-dc=it,o=us

--dc=example2,dc=it,o=us

---ou=people,dc=example2,dc=com,o=us

I've added some ACI's for cn=admin-2,dc=example,dc=com,o=us so it can manage everything from ou=people,dc=example,dc=com,o=us. Like change the passwor for uid=user3,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com,o=us

When I enter with cn=admin,o=us, all its ok. Can manage attributes and create stuff.

But when I use cn=admin-2,dc=example,dc=com,o=us I can log in phpldapadmin but on the left side corner, I see -> **? o=us** "This base entry does not exist.Create it?"

Even if I click to create it, nothing happen. It's obvious that **o=us** exist because can see it with cn=admin,o=us.

Any help with this please?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the ACLs you've added? Your ACLs probably allow the new admin accounts to modify ou=people but don't give *any* access to the rest...

Comment: access to attrs=userPassword
        by dn="cn=admin,o=us" write
        by dn="cn=admin-2,dc=example,dc=com,o=us" write
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * none

Comment: access to dn.subtree="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com,o=us"
        by dn="cn=admin-2,dc=example,dc=com,o=us" write
        by anonymous none
        by * none

Comment: If that's all, then you *do* have no ACLs at all that would grant access to `o=us`... You need an explicit `access to dn.sub="o=us"`.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Now it is working like i want.
Thank you.